# How to change datepicker language based on selected language.?

Tags: jquery, localization, datepicker

I have successful inserted datepicker into my webpage and it works smoothly now. What I need to achieve is that after changing the language from language selector, datepicker must reflect this, show the selected language text.

I have the following code, I could not manage to work it so far cause I do not know jquery well. Hope to give someone feedback

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/datepicker.core.js"></script>   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/datepicker.jquery.ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-tr.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="LanguageSelector">
                <form method="get" action="/"><select id="LanguageDropDownList" name="lang"  onchange="javascript:location='/?lang=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" ><option value="en" selected="selected" >English (en)</option><option value="tr">Türkçe (tr)</option></select><noscript><input type="submit" value=">"></noscript></form>
    </div>

        <div class="calendar" id="datepicker"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var initialCalendar = true;
            $(function() {   
                $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ ' ' ] );
                var eventDays = [<%=dateOfEvent%>];
                $('#datepicker').datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ 'tr' ],
                {         
                    inline: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onSelect: function(date) {
                        if(!initialCalendar){
                            for(var i in eventDays){
                                if(eventDays[i].Date == date){
                                    window.location = eventDays[i].Url;
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            initialCalendar = false;
                        }
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function(thedate) {
                        thedate = thedate.format("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        for(var i in eventDays){
                            if(eventDays[i].Date == thedate){
                                return [true,""];
                            }
                        }
                        return [false, ""];
                    }
                });

                $( '#LanguageDropDownList' ).change(function() {
                    $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( "option",
                        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
                });
            });

            Date.prototype.format = function(format)  
            {
               var o = {
                 "M+" : this.getMonth()+1,
                 "d+" : this.getDate(),
                 "h+" : this.getHours(),
                 "m+" : this.getMinutes(),
                 "s+" : this.getSeconds(),
                 "q+" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3),
                 "S" : this.getMilliseconds()
               }
               if(/(y+)/.test(format)) format=format.replace(RegExp.$1,
                 (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
               for(var k in o)if(new RegExp("("+ k +")").test(format))
                 format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
                   RegExp.$1.length==1 ? o[k] :
                 ("00"+ o[k]).substr((""+ o[k]).length));
               return format;
            }
         </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me from what i can see. You'll need to post your html as well. You can also create something at jsfiddle and see if it still doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine as well: http://jsfiddle.net/repw4/936/.

If it still doesn't work for you, try to destroy the datepicker and re-initiate it:

```
$('#LanguageDropDownList').change(function() {
    $('#date').datepicker('destroy')
        .datepicker($.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()]);
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/repw4/936/

Comment: Datepicker works. I only need datepicker reflect changing at LanguageDropDownList so everytime I change the language from language selector, it must set proper language

Comment: hey brother, in your js fiddle,, datepicker doesn't changed as base of language.. for every language it simply displays in english only.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the 'destroy' could remove some events if any. Try calling the ['refresh'](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh) method first, it will do a redraw:

```
$('#date').datepicker('refresh')
```